# Посчитать количество вхождений каждого слова в файле

Tags: java, файлы, java-stream

Нужно написать программу для подсчета количества вхождений каждого слова в файле используя stream api.

Comment: Т.е. сколько раз встречается слово в файле?

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то не забудьте нажать на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним

Answer (score 1):

Программа считает количество вхождений каждого слова в файле и выдает на выход `map` вида `слово:количество вхождений`.

```
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt"); //путь к файлу
Map<String, Integer> frequencyMap;

try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(path)) {
    frequencyMap = lineStream.collect(toMap(
            s -> s,
            s -> 1,
            Integer::sum));
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Способ @Anton Sorokin, похоже, считает строки.
Так будут считаться слова, но Вам надо настроить `split()` под себя

```java
Map<String, Long> cntMap;
try {
    cntMap = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\text2.txt"))
                   // разделять по знакам пунктуации (!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~) или пробелу
                  .flatMap(l -> Stream.of(l.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]")))
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    // обычный вывод
    cntMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));
    // сортированный вывод
    cntMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```